# How to extract text from log files in Python

Tags: python, string, file, logging, extract

I have found some code online and am trying to use it to extract any line of text that has the word error in it from multiple log files. I am able to read the files in the path and output them on the screen but cannot actually extract the lines that have 'error' in them.

The code that I have put together from online searches is below. When running the code, all of the .log files are shown and the output file is created, but lists the actual file name and not the lines I need. Out of the nine .log files I have, I should receive 5 lines containing errors. I did find information for extracting information from PDFs but from what I see online it is completely different than what I am trying to do.

About 4-5 times a month, we manually search anywhere from 10-50 .log files looking for errors and I want to be able to dump all the logs in a folder and run a python script to find the errors very quickly. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
import os
# defining location of parent folder
BASE_DIRECTORY = '/pending/PHS'
output_file = open('/pending/PHS/output.txt', 'w')
output = {}
file_list = []

# scanning through sub folders
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if 'log' in str(f):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            file_list.append(e)

for f in file_list:
    print(f)
txtfile = open(f, 'r')
output[f] = []

for line in txtfile:
    if 'error' in line:
        output[f].append(line)
tabs = []

for tab in output:
    tabs.append(tab)

tabs.sort()

for tab in tabs:
    output_file.write(tab + '\n')
    output_file.write('\n')

for row in output[tab]:
    output_file.write(row + '')
    output_file.write('\n')
    output_file.write('----------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

Comment: Do a Google search for 'grep'

Comment: Looks like you are writing files here, not searching/extracting anything (except "error"), in which case, `ack` or `grep` would be easier

Answer (score 0):

First one comment. It's good practice to IO files with a `with` statement that will autoclose them at the end of such statement.

```
with Open(txtfile, 'r') as txt:
    list_of_lines = txt.readlines()
```

*list_of_lines* is now loaded in memory and the read stream from txtfile is closed.

If you create these logs yourself and you know that the word "error" is exactly as is and each word is separated by a space, you could use the `str` builtin method `.split()`:

```
only_errors = []
for line in list_of_lines:
    if "error" in line.split(" "):
        only_errors.append(line)
output[txtfile] = only_errors
```

The str.split() method creates a list of strings separating words where the character you specified appears (in this case the space, " "); then the statement `if "error" in ["error", "is", "here"]` will evaluate True and proceed to append to the list the line. Note the only difference with your method is that for using the statement `xx in yy`, *yy* must be a container of several *xx* objects and not the same type of xx (in your example, they are both strings).

Personally, I use this system a lot.

The regedit module *re* is what you are looking for for more complex string pattern matching, but I will leave you with some googling to do and a link to its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

[*fuzzywuzzy*](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is another option for string matching that uses the Levenshtein distance